# Make ApplicationContext dirty before and after test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have a particular class (let's say `MyTest`) in my Spring integration tests that is using PowerMock `@PrepareForTest` annotation on a Spring component: `@PrepareForTest(MyComponent.class)`. This means that PowerMock will load this class with some modifications. The problem is, my `@ContextConfiguration` is defined on the superclass which is extended by `MyTest`, and the `ApplicationContext` is cached between different test classes. Now, if `MyTest` is run first, it will have the correct PowerMock version of `MyComponent`, but if not - the test will fail since the context will be loaded for another test (without @PrepareForTest).

So what I want to do is to reload my context before `MyTest`. I can do that via

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
```

But what if I also want to reload context after this test is done? So I will have clean `MyComponent` again without PowerMock modifications. Is there a way to do both `BEFORE_CLASS` and `AFTER_CLASS`?

For now I did it with the following hack:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
```

on MyTest and then

```
/**
 * Stub test to reload ApplicationContext before execution of real test methods of this class.
 */
@DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD)
@Test
public void aa() {
}

/**
 * Stub test to reload ApplicationContext after execution of real test methods of this class.
 */
@DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.AFTER_METHOD)
@Test
public void zz() {
}
```

I am wondering if there is a prettier way to do that?

As a side question, is it possible to reload only certain bean and not full context?

Comment: Why do you want to mark the context as dirty *before* the test?

Comment: As a said, I want to reload the context for MyTest class, so my @PrepareForTest(MyComponent.class) will work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there a way to do both BEFORE_CLASS and AFTER_CLASS?

No, that is unfortunately not supported via `@DirtiesContext`.

However, what you're really saying is that you want a new `ApplicationContext` for `MyTest` that is identical to the context for the parent test class but only lives as long as `MyTest`. And... you don't want to affect the context cached for the parent test class.

So with that in mind, the following *trick* should do the job.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// Inherit config from parent and combine with local 
// static Config class to create a new context
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext
public class MyTest extends BaseTests {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        // No need to define any actual @Bean methods.
        // We only need to add an additional @Configuration
        // class so that we get a new ApplicationContext.
    }
}
```

**Alternative to @DirtiesContext**

If you want to have a context dirtied both *before* and *after* a test class, you can implement a custom `TestExecutionListener` that does exactly that. For example, the following will do the trick.

```java
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext.HierarchyMode;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener;

public class DirtyContextBeforeAndAfterClassTestExecutionListener
        extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.markApplicationContextDirty(HierarchyMode.EXHAUSTIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.markApplicationContextDirty(HierarchyMode.EXHAUSTIVE);
    }

}
```

You can then use the custom listener in `MyTest` as follows.

```java
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode;

@TestExecutionListeners(
    listeners = DirtyContextBeforeAndAfterClassTestExecutionListener.class, 
    mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
public class MyTest extends BaseTest { /* ... */ }
```

> As a side question, is it possible to reload only certain bean and not full context?

No, that is also not possible.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `you want a new ApplicationContext for MyTest that is identical to the context for the parent test class` This is not true, because context for MyTest will not be completely the same, since it should use `@PrepareForTest(MyComponent.class)`. I tried your suggestion but encountered another issue. As I understood there will be two contexts in parallel, which is currently not possible (there is a Hazelcast instance configured and there can only be one of those on one port). I can deal with that, so I am curious how to make my Powemock annotation work on this nested context?

Comment: I updated my answer by adding a custom `TestExecutionListener` that dirties the context before and after the test class. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Yep, it does, and looks a lot better than the hack :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SamBrannen i have implemented in this fashion and after doing this started getting beanInitializationException with cyclic dependency statement, which is not the case if i don't use the listener in my child classes. on spring testing doc page https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-automatic-discovery, i see few configration advice, if i am doing for a test suite, i am also using this listener for half of my testSuite, o i need to put a file spring.factory in my jar with the custom listener entry.

Comment: @SamBrannen i have implemented in this fashion and after doing  error is https://dzone.com/articles/resolve-circular-dependency, which is not the case if i don't use the listener in my child classes. on spring testing doc page https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-automatic-discovery, i see few configration advice, if i am doing for a test suite, i am also using this listener for half of my testSuite, do i need to put a file spring.factory in my jar with the custom listener entry.

Comment: @SamBrannen Is the `@DirtiesContext` annotation on `MyTest` still necessary?